# Drop down navigation with multiple sub links

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to add a few effects to a simple CSS drop down navigation that I put together. Its almost there, just can't stop the fadeOut function calling when the nested li element is hovered on.

I have dropped it into jsfiddle, the url is: http://jsfiddle.net/6PmJk/

This is the jQuery that I am using:

```
$('body').removeClass('noJquery');
$('div#left_panel ul ul').css('display', 'none');
$('div#left_panel ul li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeIn('slow').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 150,
        top: -1,
        left: 150,
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        zIndex: 10
    });
}, 

function() {
    $('div#left_panel ul ul').stop().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only apply the `hover` rule to the "main" `ul`

```
$('div#left_panel > ul > li').hover(function() {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/6PmJk/1/

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I made that mistake!

Will mark as answered as soon as it lets me